# An initial value assumption about map in c++

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I am initializing a map `map<string,int> ex;`
in C++. I could not find contains_key or similar function in stl,
hence I am just using `ex[inputString]++;`

The debugger shows the int to be initialized to zero correctly, is it a good assumption?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, values that do not exist when accessed with `operator[]` are default-constructed. For numeric values, this is 0.

That said, you're looking for the `count` method:

```
bool hasElement = ex.count("element");
```

Comment: thanks, good to know that it is initialized to zero, saves the if !exists then initialize kind of structure needed in python

Comment: @akshayubhat C++'s `map[k]` and Python's `dict.setdefault(k[,d])` are similar in that a non-existent key will be set to a default, as C++'s `map.find(k)->second` and Python's `dict[k]` similar in that a non-existent key will give an error.  The two languages just chose different options for which to be the "common" operation.