# C++ counting instances / histogram using std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary, histogram

I have seen sample code similar to the following:

```
std::string s = "Hello World!";
std::map<char, std::size_t> h;

for (std::string::const_iterator i=s.cbegin(); i!=s.cend(); ++i)
{
    ++h[*i];
}

assert(h['l'] == 3);
```

This seems to rely on the value type being zeroed on the first occurence of each letter.  Is this guaranteed even when using something like a `std::size_t` which has no default constructor resetting it to zero?

Comment: Note: answer may be here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346481/an-initial-value-assumption-about-map-in-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed that's how `map` works: The `[]`-operator is mutating and will *create* the object of mapped type if it does not exist yet. Since `size_t` value-initializes to zero, you're all fine.

Comment: Have I missed something? Since when a POD has an initializer? Isn't this implementation-defined? Will it init to zero in release build with optimizations?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: Every declarator has an initializer. Don't confuse initialization (a grammatical concept) with construction (a function call). See 8.5 in the new standard.

Answer (score 6):

Quoting [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/80ks028k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> [POD and scalar types will always be zero initialized if instantiated
>   with the default constructor syntax.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/80ks028k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

So, assuming that map creates new entries at missing keys using a default constructor then yes, size_t will be initialised to zero.