# find two or more same elements in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

Suppose I have an array like these a[6] = {1,2,1,3,2,1,5}
 And I want to print  1,2.
 I have tried:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a[50] = {1,2,3,43,5,1,6,7,4,43,1};
    int c=0,b = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);
    for(int y=0;y<11;y++)
    {

        for(int q = y+1;q<11;q++)
        {
                        if(a[y]=a[q])
                        {
                                  cout<<a[q]<<endl;

                        }
                    }

        }
    }
```

output : 1,1,1,1,2.
And if I set the elements like {1,2,3,4,1,2}
it gives output : 1,2.

Please help me. I want to print the two or more duplicate numbers only once.

Comment: [Build a histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010761/c-counting-instances-histogram-using-stdmap).  Then print each element that has a value of 2 or more.

Comment: Instead of printing immediately you can add to some sort of [set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/) then print all of the items in the set afterwards.

Comment: also, FYI that the line `a[y]=a[q]` does not do what I think you expect ([for reference](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-and-operator-in-C++))

Comment: use `std::map` or sort your array (or a copy of it), then your task would be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to a typo in this if statement

```
if(a[y]=a[q])
      ^^^
```

There must be the comparison operator instead of the assignment.

Nevertheless if you'll update your program its algorithm will be still wrong.

A straightforward approach using loops can look the following way (I assume that the array itself may not be changed)

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 43, 5, 1, 6, 7, 4, 43, 1 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N - 1; i++ )
    {
        size_t j = 0;
        while ( j < i && a[j] != a[i] ) j++;

        if ( j++ == i )
        {
            while ( j != N && a[j] != a[i] ) j++;
            if ( j != N ) std::cout << a[j] << ' ';
        }
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 43
```

That is for each current element of the array you need to check whether it was encountered early.

Another approach is to use the standard container `std::map`.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 43, 5, 1, 6, 7, 4, 43, 1 };
    std::map<int, size_t> m;

    for ( int x : a ) ++m[x];

    for ( const auto &p : m )
    {
        if ( p.second != 1 ) std::cout << p.first << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that is a little bit more c++ish would be

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a =  { 1, 2, 3, 43, 5, 1, 6, 7, 4, 43, 1 };
    std::map<int,int> count;

    for(const auto& it:a)
    {
        auto hit = count[it]++;
        if(hit == 1)
            std::cout << it << " ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard library contains all of the bits necessary to solve this problem.  The trick is to sort the array first, which ensures that all equal elements are adjacent to each other.  We can then search the array for equal ranges.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int a[] = {1,2,3,43,5,1,6,7,4,43,1};

int main()
{
  std::sort(std::begin(a), std::end(a));

  auto current = std::begin(a);
  while (current != std::end(a))
  {
    // If the current element is followed by 1 or more equal elements, then
    // we've found a repeated value.
    auto range = std::equal_range(current + 1, std::end(a), *current);
    if (range.first != range.second)
    {
      std::cout << *begin << std::endl;
    }
    current = range.second;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope my code will help you,

I added marks on the code for help you to understand what I was done.

The idea behind my solution is to save the numbers in the new array at after that to print the elements.
if your array have a specific features (for example all the nubmers >0 ) you cand use it for mark elements (in the example of >0 you can to mark with - 1 for example ) and then pass on the array.

`#include<iostream>`

```
 //change the number 11 to define, for redability
 #define NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS 11
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {


    //new Parameters : dupArr[50] - save the duplicate numbers
    //                 count - tell us which is the last element at
    //                         b[50] that we add
    //                 iAddOneNumber - flag that tell us we add one element at  
    //                                 that iteration


        int dupArr[50]= {};
        int count=0;
        bool iAddOneNumber=false;
        int a[50] = {1,2,3,43,5,1,6,7,4,43,1,...,};
        int c=0,b = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);
        for(int curElem=0;y< NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS; curElem ++)
    {

        for(int chkElem = curElem +1; chkElem < NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS; chkElem ++){
       // you assign here and you need to add more "=" for compare
          if(a[curElem]==a[chkElem]){
             // instead of print from the condition my advice is to
             // save in another place the numbers - for example - b[50]
            if(iAddOneNumber==false){
             dupArr[count]=a[curElem];
             count++;
             iAddOneNumber=true;
            }
        }
      iAddOneNumber=false;
      }
    for(int i=0 ; i<NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS ; i++){
     if(i<count){
        std::cout << dupArr[i];   
      }
    }
  }
```

}